# Homotopy fixed points of connective K-theory

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, topological-k-theory, k-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Let $ku$ be the $p$-completion of the connective complex K-theory spectrum. The group $\Bbb{Z}_p^\times\cong \Delta \times \Bbb{Z}_p$ acts on $ku$, where $\Delta$ is the cyclic group of order $p-1$. Let $\ell$ be the connective Adams summand.

On page 4 of [this](http://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~ausoni/papers/thhku.pdf) article, it is written that $\ell \simeq ku^{h\Delta}$. Why is that? Where can I find a proof of this result?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the standard definition I believe (at least it is the one Lurie uses)

Comment: @PaxKivimae I could accept to take it as a definition, but then how do I show that $ku\simeq \bigvee_{i=0}^{p-2}\Sigma^{2i}\ell$ ?